# Count alerts fired by prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have Prometheus with some alerting rules defined and I want to have statistic regarding the number of alerts fired by Prometheus.

I tried to count how many time an alert is fired with grafana but it doesn't work:

```
SUM(ALERTS{alertname="XXX", alertstate="firing"})
```

There is a way to count how many times an alert is fired?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your query returns how many alerts are firing now, not how many times each alert was fired.

I've found this query to (mostly) work with Prometheus 2.4.0 and later:

```
changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE[24h])
```

It will return the number of times each alert went from "pending" to "firing" during the last 24 hours, meaning it will only work for alerts that have a pending state in the first place (i.e. alerts with `for: <some_duration>` specified).

`ALERTS_FOR_STATE` is a newly added Prometheus-internal metric that is used for restoring alerts after a Prometheus restart. It's not all that well documented (not at all, actually), but it seems to work.

Oh, and if you want the results grouped by alert (or environment, or job, or whatever) you can sum the results by that label or set of labels:

```
sum by(alertname) (changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE[24h]))
```

will give you how many times each alert fired across jobs, environments etc.

Comment: The good [article](https://tiantiankan.me/a/5cf5562daada82366d5adebd) about this topic.
We have to add one because going from not existing to existing is not counted as a change in value for the purpose of changes.

Comment: As noted in the response, ALERTS_FOR_STATE is used for restoring alerts across restarts. It changes whenever an alert enters the pending state (not when it changes from pending -> firing). It may also change whenever prometheus restarts, for pending alerts specifically. So this may not provide an accurate count of how many times an alert has fired.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by "Alin Sînpălean", I count the alerts of `firing` state and ignore the `pending` state.

- Count current alerts:

  ```
  count(ALERTS{alertstate="firing"}) by(alertname)
  ```
- Count how many times each alert has been triggered:

  ```
  # Add a rule
  groups:
  - name: recording_rules
    rules:
    - record: ALERTS_FOR_STATE:firing
      expr: ALERTS_FOR_STATE and ignoring(alertstate) ALERTS{alertstate="firing"}
  ```

  ```
  sum(changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE:firing[1w]) + 1) by(alertname)
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Your PromQL is correct. Keep in mind though that labels (including alertname) are case sensitive: perhaps this is the issue?